How to open CSV file in R when R says "no such file or directory"? How can I fix this problem with the file and the directory?
I downloaded some tsv files and converted them to csv. Now I would like to read them with "Rstudio" but once I select the directory and read.csv Rstudio tells me "no such file or directory". How can I solve the problem?
enter image description here
I tried to upload the file as I always do by changing the directory as it is contained in a new folder. Also to be sure I clicked from "session" -> "set working directory" -> "to source file location".  In any case the software response is always this: " In file(file, "rt"):
the file 'estat_tessi171.csv' cannot be opened: No such file or directory

".


This question is similar to: How to open CSV file in R when R says "no such file or directory"?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
